# My output from a custom dialect is not using double quotes in procesing a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am using Python 3.6.6.  I have the following code and based on what I read and examples I saw it seems this should be quoting everything with double quotes.  However I only see single quotes in my output:

```
import os
import csv

csv.register_dialect('pipes', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter='|', quotechar = '"',)
with open("C:\\test3\\pymorsel\\fixcsv\\sourcefile.psv", 'r') as f:
    sourceFile = csv.reader(f, dialect='pipes')
    for row in sourceFile:
        print(row)
```

My input file:

```
Reading|Make|Model|Type|Value
Reading 0|Toyota|"Previa"|distance|19.83942
Reading 1|Dodge|Intrepid, test|distance|31.28257
```

My output:

```
['Reading', 'Make', 'Model', 'Type', 'Value']
['Reading 0', 'Toyota', 'Previa', 'distance', '19.83942']
['Reading 1', 'Dodge', 'Intrepid, test', 'distance', '31.28257']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the Python object.

You should use the `csv.writer.writerow` writer object function to write the output.

For instance:

```
    sourceFile = csv.reader(f, dialect='pipes')
    w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    for row in sourceFile:
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: that worked exactly as I hoped.  Thank you for your help.